How Strong does the tidal force has to be to pull debris off a planet?
How strong do tidal forces have to be to rip stuff off of a planet? I have this question:

A planet covered in loose debris with radius $r$ orbits a black hole of mass $M=1\cdot 10^{35} \text{ kg}$ in a circular orbit of radius $R$. The planet is tidally locked, meaning the same side of it is always facing the black hole. If the planet and the debris have density $\rho=2000 \text{ kg/m}^3$, what is the minimum value of $R$ such that the debris stays attached to the planet? Assume the planet remains spherical and $R\gg r$. Give your answer in $\text{AU}$.

And then I equate the tidal forces which according to Newtonian gravity get to a maximum of around $2GMr/R^3$, but my answer doesn't match the given solution. So is my intuition of the tidal force having to be larger than the gravitational force, and limiting equality being the solution not right?

I suggest whoever voted to close this question reread the rules about good homework questions. In my opinion, this post is equivalent to some of the examples of good homework questions we have on this site.

How are you dealing with the centripetal acceleration of the debris sitting on the spinning planet?

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 I'm sorry but this is nowhere near a "good homework question".

@SUI Note that a black hole isn't correctly described by Newtonian gravity; general relativity is needed unless you're working in the Newtonian limit. You haven't provided much information so it's hard to tell.

Note that your answer does not have units of length.

@VincentThacker The OP is not trying to get a numerical answer. He/she is asking about the concepts required for a correct answer. Looking at the examples of good homework questions on this site, I cannot see what is wrong. Maybe you could clarify why you think this question is not acceptable.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 Sure, it might not be a direct "do the work for me" question, but it is rather unclear on at least two points. (1) "answer doesn't match the key" The OP has not provided anything about what the "correct" answer should be; and (2) The question is also lacking in context as a black hole requires GR to describe accurately whereas the OP is trying to use Newtonian gravity. So due to the aforementioned reasons, it is unclear to me what the correct concept is and where the OP is incorrect due to the lack of a provided solution.

@SUI This post and this paper might help you in computing the tidal forces of a black hole.

@SUI For a more complete derivation see section 32.6 of MTW.

@VincentThacker In your judgment, the correct reason for closing should have been "lack of clarity," not "Homework or homework-like."

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 (1) I don't have complete control over the final close reason and (2) Incorrect close reason isn't an argument for reopening the question; a different close reason can be selected from the "Leave Closed" menu in the reopen queue.
